# How can I determine whether a Steam game can be activated on Origin as well?

Tags: steam, origin

As described by title, I own a certain number of games on Steam. How can I determine whether a Steam game can be activated on Origin as well?

Comment: Given the animosity between EA and Valve, likely none.

Comment: Are we planning to keep this list up-to-date going forward?  This feels like it might work better as "How can I determine whether a Steam game can be activated on Origin as well?"

Comment: @bwarner Agreed

Comment: Mass Effect (1) can be activated via https://activate.ea.com/activategame.do
You will need to create or link "EA Classic Screen name" to your EA/Origin account for that (I had an account on pogo.com and it allowed me to link that).
After refreshing games list ME1 appeared in Origin client. Crysis still wouldn't activate any way though.
So it's not a universal way for activating older games, but some might work.

Comment: If you have a serial of the game, you can usually just insert that in Origin in its "redeem a game code" function. I added my store-bought Mirror's Edge that way. It's always worth a try :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

This list was obtained [here](http://techgage.com/article/migrating_your_ea_games_from_steam_or_retail_to_origin/). In addition, the following Steam games also can be activated on Origin:

```
+---------------------------------------+-------------------+
|              Game Title               | Can be activated? |
+---------------------------------------+-------------------+
| Command & Conquer - Red Alert 3       | Yes               |
| Dragon Age:Origins - Ultimate Edition | Yes               |
+---------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

If you have an EA Game not listed here that you can retrieve the CD Key from Steam you can try to activate it on Origin and even if it doesn't work, you may be able to contact support and get them to activate it.

Comment: Nice, just a question, if I activate them on Origin will be still playable on Steam forever?

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to use them with either service.

Comment: Just FYI, I had to activate Bad Company 2 on the activation website. Origin tells you to if you try to register it through the client, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an official list of redeemable games on [Origin Code Redemption FAQ](http://help.ea.com/article/origin-code-redemption-faq). This is the up-to-date list of games accepted:

> Can I add an EA game that I purchased outside of Origin to my Origin
>   Game Library? Currently all EA games released in 2009 or later can be
>   added to your Origin Game Library.  We’re working to enable this
>   option for EA’s older titles as well. At this point, all of the
>   following titles are enabled for this feature:
>
> ```
> Alice 2: Madness Returns
> Battlefield 3
> Burnout Paradise
> Command & Conquer 4: Tiberium Twilight
> Command & Conquer: Red Alert 3
> Command & Conquer: Red Alert 3: Uprising
> EA Create
> Crysis 2
> Darkspore
> Dead Space
> Dead Space 2
> Dragon Age: Origins
> Dragon Age: Origins Awakening
> Dragon Age 2
> FIFA Manager 09
> FIFA Manager 10
> FIFA Manager 11
> FIFA Manager 12
> FIFA Soccer 09
> FIFA Soccer 10
> FIFA Soccer 11
> FIFA Soccer 12
> Gattling Gears
> Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1 
> Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2
> Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince
> Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning (Non-Steam)
> Mass Effect 2
> Mass Effect 3
> Medal of Honor
> Mirror's Edge
> MySims 
> Need For Speed: Hot Pursuit
> Need For Speed: Shift
> Need For Speed: The Run
> Need For Speed: Undercover
> NHL 09
> Shank
> Shift 2 Unleashed
> SimCity 4 Deluxe Edition 
> The Lord Of The Rings: Conquest
> The Saboteur
> The Sims Medieval
> The Sims Medieval Pirates and Nobles
> ```